# What is axios rate limit?

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, express, axios

Does anyone know's the rate limit of the axios api because it is throwing a lot of 429 errors when i am using it

here is my codes

```
const instance = axios.create({ baseURL: 'http://9rv324283.ngrok.io' })

<NavigationEvents
onWillFocus={() => {

  try {

    const response = await instance.get('fetchNewDishes');

    this.setState({data: response.data})

  } catch(err) {

    console.log(err)

  }

}}>

<TouchableOpacity onPress={() =>  instance.patch(`/postNewDish/${this.state.dish}`)}>
            <Text style={{ fontSize: 16, color: '#555', padding: 15 }}>Post Dish</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) is an Http Client. Http Clients won't have a rate limit. However, API's typically have rate limiting implemented (especially public onces). The error message you're receiving is saying the following:

> The HTTP 429 Too Many Requests response status code indicates the user
> has sent too many requests in a given amount of time ("rate
> limiting").

With that being said, the only thing you can do on your side is make requests less frequently. Rate Limiting is something implemented by the API you're using. You should consult their documentation to figure out the specifics on what their rate limits are.